# How to programmatically differentiate between Virtual Drive created by subst command and actual removable drive

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

When we attach removable drive, OS assigns drive letter to it. Other way is to use subst command to map local folder to any drive.
I am  writing the hook to Explorer where I need to differentiate between these two drives.
I tried to use GetVolumePathName but it is not working correctly for virtual drives.

Comment: Your "virtual" vs "removable" drives is a misconception. The whole drive letter thing is a virtual layer, ie. the first drive letter is not equal to the drive and not special in any way. The most direct path you can get is something like `\\.\PhysicalDrive2`, and everything else is an alias to this.

Comment: @deviantfan, drive letters usually link to volumes created by a filesystem driver, e.g. the `C:` drive might link to `\Device\HardddiskVolume1`. OTOH, `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` is a link to a raw device such as `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`. Call [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the target. A drive letter created by `subst` should resolve to a path such as `\??\C:\Substitute\Path`.

Comment: Thanks @deviantfan and eryksun. I guess I need to explore more about volumes also I will try using QueryDosService().

Comment: @eryksun I tried QueryDosDevice() it fails for virtual drive and gives device path for other drives. It solved my purpose except one scenario. It also fails to give device name for the folder one which actual device is mapped. The revers of virtual drive scenario. So I used API GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint() which solve my purpose. Thanks

Comment: @eryksun WinObj is sysinternals tool. I want to check all these using some API in my code. So I can not use this tool.

Comment: I mentioned WinObj as a tool to explore the object namespace, not as a solution to your problem. I thought `QueryDosDevice` would suffice as part of an overall solution. It shouldn't fail, unless you query a path instead of just the device name (e.g. "Z:" or "Volume{GUID}" should work). Anyway, `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` is simpler since it gives you a boolean answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the question by just adding one additional verification step.

Suppose I mapped c:\Folder1 to z:.

I have a path z:\file1.txt. If I try to get the mount point using API GetVolumePathName() then it fails so I can guess that z:\ is nothing but the virtual drive which is pointing to some folder in other drive.

But If I have a path z:\Folder2\file1.txt then GetVolumePathName() gives me Mount Point as z:\Folder2. I do not understand why. But to verify that whether it is actually pointing to any device volume I used API GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint() to get volume name of Mount Point return above. If Mount Point is for any device then it returns the actual volume name GUID of that device else it fails (for virtual drive).

Now to know if Mount Point return above is FIXED or REMOVABLE use GetDriveType() if it returns
DRIVE_FIXED then it is fixed drive else
DRIVE_REMOVABLE then it is removable.

It solved my purpose.